# how can I determine if a user is within a property line

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I would like to take a longitude and latitude of a user and determine if they are within a set boundary of property line on the map similar to the rectangles symbolizing buildings.I have looked into using [`CLGeocoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder) which returns an address but I would like to be able to determine if the user is within a park, or a property, a neighborhood or even a building which may have multiple addresses within it. What is the best way to go about doing this thank you.

[image: map with boundaries]

Comment: Sounds like geofencing.

Comment: This question is to broad but I think you would need to overlay the map with a grid, check what squares (or rectangles) the building etc occupies and see if the users´is within any of those squares. Looks very complicated

Comment: @rmaddy It is a kind of geofencing but Im not quite sure how to access the data correctly to check if a longitude and latitude are within the bounds of the geofence created as a property rectangle by apple on their maps. I know the data must exist as its used for mkoverlays native to mkmapkit but Im not sure if there is a way to access it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That sounds a little bit like reconstructing a map ontop of the map view. This data must already exist as the boundaries are defined natively in map kit as mkoverlay in the form of rectangles as shown in the image. Im just not sure how to access these boundaries and check if a longitude and latitude are contained within them.

Comment: I didn't know about MKOverlay but after briefly reading the documentation I get the impression you still need to configure them yourself so it's not that different from what I suggested.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how would you recommend figuring out the boundaries of the rectangular overlays of the buildings?